# Подставить значения в тег из базы данных

Tags: php, база-данных

> Как в тег option подставлять значения из таблицы goods БД: value="6300", data-link="http://ecoskarb.ru/products/287778/belava". Эти значения попадут в функцию jquery. Сложность в том, что массив описан для другои таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ничоси какая у вас расцветка модная...

Comment: @Manitikyl потому что 3 раз пытаюсь объяснить один вопрос :D

Comment: кто-нибудь поможет или так и будете смеяться...(

Comment: Мы бы вам помогли, но ваш вопрос непонятен.

Comment: @Manitikyl Как взять данные из таблицы БД и подставить в тег?

Comment: покажите вывод команды var_dump($item['sub']); и запрос из которого формируется переменная $cat

Comment: Что надо подставить - это понятно. Больше ничего не понятно. Взять данные запросом - http://php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php . Подставить - там есть примеры.

Comment: Array(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Двухъярусная кровать
            [sub] => Array
                (
                    [7] => Белава
                    [21] => Двуспальная
                    [14] => Домик
                 )
        )

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer